# Setting time field in django such that the stored time cannot be changed later

Tags: django

I have a orders model which looks like this:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    date_ordered=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    complete=models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True,blank=False)
```

and this is a specific view from my views.py:

```
def handlerequest(request, id):
    order=Order.objects.get(id=id)
    items=order.orderitem_set.all()
    verify = Checksum.verify_checksum(response_dict, MERCHANT_KEY, checksum)
    PaytmHistory.objects.create(**response_dict)
    if verify:
        if response_dict['RESPCODE'] == '01':
            order.transaction_id=transaction_id
            order.complete=True               
            order.save()
            print('order successful')
```

Now what is happening is that whenever this is view is called the order is saved and the time updates to when the order was saved. But in future when I manually make some changes to the fields like when I update the shipping status of the order and save it then the time updates which I dont want . So is there any fix to this such that after

```
order.complete=True               
order.save()
```

The time cannot be changed

Comment: check [auto_now_add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add)

Answer (score 1):

As documentation states [auto_now](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now)

> Automatically set the field to now every time the object is saved.
> Useful for “last-modified” timestamps. Note that the current date is
> always used; it’s not just a default value that you can override.

You should use [auto_now_add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) instead

> automatically set the field to now when the object is first created.
> Useful for creation of timestamps.

---

Your field is still auto_now so you should remove auto_now from it and make it NULL=True, also you should set time value when you complete order and that is it.

Comment: I think this wont help me because my order object is created once a user logs in to his account and what I want is that once he has ordered(`order.complete=true`) that time is saved and cannot be changed later

Answer (score 1):

- Override the model `save()`
- Check if `Order.complete` is `True`
- Save with `Order.date_ordered` equal to current datetime when and only if `Order.complete` is `True`
- `date_odered` field set to `null=True, blank=True`

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    date_ordered=models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    complete=models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True,blank=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.complete == True:
            self.date_ordered = datetime.now

        super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: what does super do? and will it be ok if I dont put args and kwargs

Comment: @VATSALJAIN `super()` is a function which is used to refer the parent and access its properties and methods. save() is an inherited method from `models.Model`. By using super() we are accessing the save() method. It's best to keep the *args and **kwargs as such since we are overriding the parent method we don't want to have any other problems related to our model